# LeetCode 1: Two Sum - addressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address

Tags: c++

This is my code, but I don't see anything wrong with it. This is the [twoSum problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) on LeetCode, and it's also my first time using c++.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {\
        vector<int> arr(2);
         
        for (int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            
            for(int j=i+1; i<nums.size();j++){
                
                if (nums[i]+nums[j]==target){
                    arr[0]=i;
                    arr[1]=j;         
                }
    
            }
            
            
        }
            return arr;
       
    }
};
```

Comment: `for(int j=i+1; i<nums.size();j++){` This checks one variable, but increments another.

Comment: oh thank you sm im dumb i didn't see that

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int j=i+1; i<nums.size();j++)
```

checks the `i` value but increments `j`. You probably want something like:

```
for(int j=i+1; j<nums.size();j++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your bug, but here is an efficient working solution for the Two Sum problem:

- We use an `unordered_map` for mapping our indices.
- We'd only loop through the elements once (`O(N)` time complexity) and we would record our indices.
- Finally, we would just add an `if` statement to return the desired output using `std::vector<int> {index, iter->second};`, for which we can also use `std::array`, if you want.

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Solution {
public:
    static std::vector<int> twoSum(const std::vector<int> &nums, const int target) {
        std::unordered_map<int, int> index_map;

        for (int index = 0;; index++) {
            auto iter = index_map.find(target - nums[index]);

            if (iter != index_map.end())
                return std::vector<int> {index, iter->second};

            index_map[nums[index]] = index;
        }
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic time/space complexity analysis in there.